# ServiceStack Facebook Authentication NullReference Exception on Vagrant Box (Ubuntu/MySql/Mono/nginx)

Tags: servicestack

Long shot I guess, with the lack of real information that I am offering at this stage. I'll gladly offer up some more details on how to reproduce the issue - but wanted some fast feedback to see if there was a *gotcha* somewhere I was missing.

I've a simple ServiceStack hello world application, in which I'm playing with the Facebook Auth Provider:

- Vanilla ServiceStack
- Vanilla Facebook Auth Proivider
- Vanilla User Session
- Vanilla OrmLite User Repository
- Vanilla OrmLite MySql Db Factory

When debugging on my local machine - on Windows 7 (and 8); everything works a treat. The service launches, the database tables are created and I can login via Facebook and records are inserted to the relevant tables.

When running the service on Ubuntu inside a Vagrant Box (running in Virtual Box as the provider for virtualization, hosted on nginx with mono-fastcgi) - the service launches correctly and I can see that the tables are created in the MySql database. When I hit `/auth/facebook` I am *correctly* forwarded to Facebook - but I hit an error when the callback to the service occurs.

This is the current output:

```
[Auth: 07/30/2013 13:02:47]: [REQUEST: {provider:facebook}] System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at 
ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.FacebookAuthProvider.Authenticate (ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.IServiceBase,ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.IAuthSession,ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.Auth) <0x0061e> at 
ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.AuthService.Authenticate (ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.Auth,string,ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.IAuthSession,ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.IAuthProvider) <0x000a7> at 
ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.AuthService.Post (ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.Auth) <0x00303> at 
ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.AuthService.Get (ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.Auth) <0x00013> at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.lambda_method (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,object,object) <0x0004f> at 
ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ServiceRunner`1<ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.Auth>.Execute (ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IRequestContext,object,ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.Auth) <0x00416>
```

It is clearly reaching the Service (which I'm accessing via `localhost:8080` which maps through to the guest machine on port 80); as the error is wrapped nicely in ServiceStack output.

I don't suppose anyone has any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay after an evening of investigation - I've found the root cause.

[Line 51 of FacebookAuthProvider.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/FacebookAuthProvider.cs#L51) calls off to [Line 28 of WebRequestExtensions.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/WebRequestExtensions.cs#L165) - which in turn calls [Line 227 of WebRequestExtensions.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/WebRequestExtensions.cs#L165).

This method call [fails at line 255-ish](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/WebRequestExtensions.cs#L255) - essentially because Mono by default doesn't trust any SSL certificates by default: [as explained here.](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ%3a_Security).

Instead of figuring out the correct configuration for Mono - I've taken the nasty route (for the time being at least); of using the following line in my `AppHostBase.Configure` implementation:

**F#**

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback <- new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(fun _ _ _ _ -> true)
```

**C#**

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (a, b, c, d) => { return true; };
```

I am now up and running (like a fully-operational Death Star).